# Выставление поля по умолчанию Python Django

Tags: python, django

Не могу понять, как сделать чтобы поле user_id заполнялось автоматически, User всегда аунтифицирован. Пытался добавлять в поле default = User.username, это ничего не дало

views.py

```
def addFile(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('%s?next=%s' % (settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL, request.path))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('storage')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = AddFileForm()

    return render(request, 'MainStorage/addfile.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py

```
class SaveFile(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField("Наименование", max_length=255)
    saveFile = models.FileField("Файл", upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d/')
    file_describe = models.CharField("Описание", max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    time_save = models.DateTimeField("Дата загрузки", auto_now_add=True)
    time_update = models.DateTimeField("Дата редактирования", auto_now=True)
```

forms.py

```
class AddFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SaveFile
        fields = ['title', 'saveFile', 'file_describe']
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input'}),
            'file_describe': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 30, 'rows': 2}),
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Помогло следующие:

views.py

```
def addFile(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('%s?next=%s' % (settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL, request.path))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_file = form.save(commit=False)
            new_file.user_id = request.user
            new_file.save()
            return redirect('storage')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = AddFileForm()
```

admin.py (Важно!)

```
class NewFileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('user_id',)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not obj.pk:
            obj.user_id = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

forms.py

```
class AddFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SaveFile
        fields = ['title', 'saveFile', 'file_describe']
        exclude = ['user_id']
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input'}),
            'file_describe': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 30, 'rows': 2}),
        }
```